# How to highlight floating numbers and integers differently in .F90 files in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fortran, elisp

How to highlight floating numbers and integers differently in .F90 files in Emacs? In my version 24.4.1, there is no difference between floating numbers and integers. How can I display them in different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question two weeks ago. Now I have had my own solution. So, I am posting it here as a reference for others who might encountered the same.

First of all, I'd love to thank *@Justin* for answering before and suggesting the `highlight-number-mode`. His solution probably works. However, I have a slightly more complicated requirement, so I decided to do it differently.

Also, I'd have to admit that I'm a very beginner in programming. So, you might find some stupid lines in my codes. Feel free to let me know if you think there's a better way.

Here is my **solution**.

1. Install `highlight-number-mode` and `parent-mode` in emacs. (The second one is required by the first one.) In my case, they are installed under /`~/.emcas.d/elpa/`.
2. As far as I see, the original `highlight-number-mode` does not support `f90-mode`, and it highlights all numbers (eg. 2, 3.4, 8e-2) equally, by changing fond color. This does not meet my requirement. Specifically, I wish to highlight only floating numbers, and I denoting them either as **2.** or **.5** in my .f90 script. In Fortran 90, floats and integers have different division rules. So, I hope to visualize them differently in order to reduce the risk of introducing such bugs. Therefore, I changed the following part in the source code (`highlight-numbers.el`):

> ```
> (defconst highlight-numbers-generic-regexp
>   (rx (or
>        "."
>        (? (and
>            symbol-start
>            digit
>            symbol-end)
>           "."
>           (* digit))))
>   "Generic regexp for number highlighting.
> It is used when no mode-specific one is available.")
>
> (defvar highlight-numbers-modelist
>   (copy-hash-table
>    (eval-when-compile
>      (let ((table (make-hash-table :test 'eq)))
>
>        (puthash 'f90-mode
>                 (rx (or
>                      "."
>                      (? (and
>                          symbol-start
>                          (or (and (+ digit) (? (or "." "e" ".e" "E" ".E")) (+ digit))
>                          (and (+ digit) (? (or "e-" ".e-" "E-" ".E-")) (+ digit))
>                          (and (+ digit) "." (+ digit) (? (or "e" "E")) (+ digit))
>                          (* digit))        
>                          symbol-end)
>                         "."
>                         (* digit))))
>                  table)
> ```

If you compare the above code with the original one by *Fanael Linithien*, you will notice that I have added two `"."`. As Fanael said (in private discussions), this is probably due to that `"."` is taken as a punctuation in f90-mode in emacs. So, I have to modify the regexp and the table accordingly.

3. Once the above has been done, I put the line `(add-hook 'f90-mode-hook 'highlight-numbers-mode)` in my `init.el` to load this package via elpa.
4. Afterwards, the floats in my code will be highlighted, such as

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJjO0.png)

And you can see the difference in floats and integers.

In the end, I'd add that I have been using this for quite a few days. No problems happen so far. So, I guess it is working! :)

Comment: It works, thank you! I changed the existing highlight-numbers.el file in my elpa folder and re-compiled via M-x byte-recompile-directory RET ~/.emacs.d/elpa/

Answer (score 2):

The default emacs fortran mode doesn't differentiate the font faces for floats and integers.  However, you could use the `highlight-numbers` package (via `M-x package-list-packages` or https://github.com/Fanael/highlight-numbers).

Add the following to your `.emacs` to highlight floats (change the foreground and background colors as you see fit:

```
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook 'highlight-numbers-mode)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
      (lambda ()
        (puthash 'fortran-mode
                 (rx (and symbol-start
                          (? "-")
                          (+ digit)
                          "."
                          (+ digit)
                          (*? any)
                          symbol-end))
                 highlight-numbers-modelist)
        (set-face-attribute 'highlight-numbers-number nil
                            :foreground "gray60" :background "black")))
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for answering. I have installed highlight-numbers-mode and parent-mode. However, putting what you suggested in my init.el gives an error: "Symbol's value as variable is void: highlight-numbers-modelist".

Comment: I have also tried to add a fortran-mode in the highlight-numbers.el directly, then later enable this package manually. But it still doesn't differentiate floats and integers. They become a different color together. Can you explain what you wrote in the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure putting the code above in `init.el` would work, I added it to my `~/.emacs`. The error suggests that the `highlight-numbers` package hasn't been initialized yet. As to your second comment, that probably means that `highlight-numbers-mode` is active, but using the default pattern match, with highlights both floats and integers. The code that I wrote above causes only floats to be highlighted.

Comment: I tried to put it in ~/.emacs, not working either. But I can initialize the package via the first hook (in my case, f90-mode). So, I was trying to modify the source .el script. So far, I have only been able to highlight d.d format (eg. 2.3), but not 2. or .2 etc (which is what I want the most). Do you know how to write a rx such that d. and .d can also be highlighted? (lisp is really confusing to me...)

Comment: `~/.emacs` and `~/.emacs.d/init.el` are functionally equivalent.  Pick one and don't use the other (I like `init.el` because then everything is in one directory).  

`highlight-numbers-modelist` is not autoloaded.  Just wrap the code that uses it with `(with-eval-after-load 'highlight-numbers ...)`.  That will run the wrapped code after the library is loaded, thus everything will be defined.